# Homeomorphism of connected sets

Tags: general-topology

If we consider two subsets of the Euclidean Plane with the standard topology, if one is connected and the other isn't, is this enough to say they are not homeomorphic? We assume both sets inherit the standard topology. I guess I'm confused about these sets, say $U$ and $V$, being 'topological spaces' when considering the inherited topology, in regards to the fact that connectedness is a topological property. I could possibly tackle this problem (for a maths class, I won't list it here, but the goal is to show two specific subsets of the plane are not homeomorphic) by just focusing on bijectiveness/continuity and it may be easier, but so far I wanted to see if a solution with connectedness was possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the relevant result:

> The image of a connected space under a continuous map is also connected. That is, let $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, and let $f \colon X \longrightarrow Y$ be a continuous mapping. If $X$ is connected, then so is $f(X)$, regarded as a subspace of $Y$. Thus if $f$ is also surjective and continuous and $X$ is connected, then so is $Y$.

For a proof, please refer to Sec. 23 in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition.

Thus a connected topological space cannot be homeomorphic with a non-connected one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is for subsets $U$ and $V$ of a topological space, with the inherited topology, can these 'subspaces' be considered topological spaces?

Comment: @ThunderHex: Yes, they can.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was after

Comment: This result generalizes the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: In what way? Would you be able to elaborate?